# Returning status 400 in gRPC with go

Tags: go, error-handling, grpc, 400-bad-request

I am used to write Rest API endpoints, wherein we insert error codes like 400 directly in the response.

```
return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
```

I have a piece of golang code(part of gRPC API) returning an error, like:

```
status.Errorf(codes.FailedPrecondition, ...custom error)
```

How do we map it to status 400?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question? A http's `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` (code `400`) might be `codes.InvalidArgument` (code: `3`), indicating that the request came with invalid data and the user might retry with a proper request. Is that all what you wanted to know?

Comment: `Precondition Failed` (code `412`) would be gRPC's `codes.FailedPrecondition` mapped to http, if that's what you've meant.

Comment: FailedPrecondition is actually getting mapped to code 500 on client side. I guess  InvalidArgument is one which would map to 400.

Comment: Well, `500` is just more generic, but can be used as well. Still not sure that was all you questions was about, though. :)